# Speed Up Spring MockMvc Integration Test with Embedded Cassandra

Tags: java, junit, cassandra, spring-test

We are using MockMvc Framework to test Spring Controllers with JUnit. Controller returns a `DefferedResult`.

The `mockmvc.perform` looks like bellow

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/customer")
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, "xyz")
                .header(FROM_KEY, "email@gmail.com")
                .content(json)
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(request().asyncStarted());
```

And it takes a lot of time. **We are Using embedded cassandra and because of that it takes a lot of time.**

I tried this as well, but it's same.

```
MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/customer")
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, "xyz")
            .header(FROM_KEY, "email@gmail.com")
            .content(json)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andReturn();

mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(request().asyncStarted());
```

I've hundreds of tests, because of which the build process is really slow.

Is there a way, using JUnit I can say perform the request and wait for response in another thread to assert the results, Or anyother good way of speeding it up.

Thanks

Comment: I think the best way to get an answer for this is to create a full end-to-end snippet e.g. hosted on a GitHub page somewhere so people can pull down have a play about with and see the performance stats themselves.  Due to the nature of this (integration testing) I doubt if you'll get an accurate and helpful answer without supplying some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my question *We are Using embedded cassandra and because of that it takes a lot of time.*

I tried looking things in `cassandra.yaml` file and changed the line below.

```
commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms: 90
```

to

```
commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms: 1
```

That's all and the build time was reduced from 30 minutes to 2 minutes.

From cassandra.yaml comments:-

> *It will wait up to `commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms` milliseconds for other writes, before performing the sync.*

After reducing this time the wait time was reduced and build time got reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the Cassandra/Persistence-Layer of your application for this test?

If the anser is no, or if the answer is no a wide array of tests cases, than you could inject another persitsence repoitory when running tests. To achive this, you could use Spring's built in `Profile` functionality and annotate your tests accordingly, for example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfile("StubPersistence")
public class WebLayerIntegrationTests {
...
}
```

You could then have a stubbed version of your Cassanda-Repository for your tests, that are allowed to work with static data:

```
@Profiles("StubPersistence")
@Repository
public class StubCassandaRepository {
    ...
}
```

This class could be backed by a simple data structure like a `HashSet` or similar, depdends on your use case. The possibility of this approach depdens heavy on your software architecture, so it might not be possible if you can't stub out your Cassandra depdencies.

I also wonder if you really need hundreds of test, that need your complete application, including the web layer. You can of course significantly speed up your tests by favoring Unit-Tests over Integration-Tests, so that you don't need to initiliaze the Spring-Context. Depends on your application and software architecture as well.

There will also be some testing improvements in Spring-Boot 1.4 that will allow you to specifically initilize single slices of your application for testing (like Persistence, or Web-Layer):
https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4

So, my best advice is:
If you want to test your Controllers, test only your Controllers and not your Persistence-Layer, stub it out instead. If you want to test your Persistence-Layer, start with the interfaces of your Persistence-Layer, don't use your Controllers as the test-interface.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the following?

1. Running as a "Spring Integration Test"? e.g.

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(classes = CassandraConfig.class)
   public class BookRepositoryIntegrationTest {
     //
   }
   ```
2. Are you starting and stopping the embedded Casandra server using the *@BeforeClass* / *@AfterClass`* annotations? e.g.

   ```
   @BeforeClass
   public static void startCassandraEmbedded() { 
       EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.startEmbeddedCassandra(); 
       Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
         .addContactPoints("127.0.0.1").withPort(9142).build();
       Session session = cluster.connect(); 
   }

   ... and ...

   @AfterClass
   public static void stopCassandraEmbedded() {
       EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.cleanEmbeddedCassandra();
   }
   ```

See http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-tutorial for more information

Comment: yeah, we are running it `Spring Integration Test` and we are not *starting and stopping* cassandra before every class, because I think cassandra server startup and running migrations will increase the time.

Comment: OK great, have you identified where the slowness is?   Is it possibly `DeferredResult`?  Is it handled currently on another thread?

Comment: nope, actually we do all the task and then get the result, wrap it in `DeferredResult` and return it from method.